# How to return an array from a Excel udf?

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

I would like to return a 2d array from my Excel UDF but it only seems to return the 1st element:

```
public object[,] Get2DArray()
{         
     object [,] a = new object[2, 2];
     a[0,0] = 0;
     a[0,1] = 1;
     a[1,0] = 2;
     a[1,1] = 3;
     return a;
}
```

Where invocation looks like:

```
=Get2DArray()
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: the size of the array may change from time to time so I don't want to have to specify the size of the range the result will fill.

Comment: why not use a list ? or IEnumerable?

Comment: What do you mean by it returns only 1st element? Show the code on the excel side that is assigning the content of the array to a range.

Comment: Mortalus, I can use a list but I seem to need to specify a range that the data should be populated to before entering the formula. I don't want to do this, I would prefer to leave the formula in a cell and then when it has data it should populate all the cells below the one the formula exists in.

Comment: shahkalpesh, see above: =Get2DArray()

Comment: There's an Excel-DNA example of how to make an auto-resizing array function - see http://excel-dna.net/2011/01/30/resizing-excel-udf-result-arrays/

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a 2 dimensional array, the content of the array can't be assigned to a **single** cell.

From your example, you are returning a 2x2 array - select a range (which is of exact size) and write the formula in the 1st cell of the selection.
For e.g. say you select A1 to B2, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, type in the formula in cell A1 (while the selection is active) and then you should be able to see the values written to B1, A2, B2 as well.

I understand that the return value array can be dynamic. I don't know how this can be handled. However, you can get this done in VBA than using UDFs.

Comment: Still only gives the first element with a 1d array

Comment: It shows 0. I think I need to use Application.Caller and derive the address from there.

Comment: Remember to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the array formula (after selecting the 2x2 range and typing in the formula. The formula should display with brackets around, as {=Get2DArray()} (though not entered that way).